# Netbeans get Error build.xml

Tags: java, netbeans-7

When I build and Clean (Shift+F11)my Project on Netbean 7.3 get Error

nbproject\build-impl.xml:951: The following error occurred while executing this line:
nbproject\build-impl.xml:293: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Answer (score 2):

Please check that the build xml is proper and valid and the targets are clearly mentioned .

Also try to do an ant build from the command line